# Stellar_core_commander: Getting an exception trying to run "scc -r base.rb"

Tags: stellar-core

Stellar's utility ("[Stellar_Core_Commander](https://github.com/stellar/stellar_core_commander)") is a tool used to deterministically create snapshots of the SQL DB by running a set of stellar operations. Its written in ruby. To run it, you need to install the relevant Gem file and run:

```
scc -r <a commands file>
```

however, its throwing an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
4: from /var/lib/postgresql/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/scc:23:in `<main>'
3: from /var/lib/postgresql/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/scc:23:in `load'
2: from 

/var/lib/postgresql/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/stellar_core_commander-0.0.12/bin/scc:135:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /var/lib/postgresql/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/stellar_core_commander-0.0.12/bin/scc:71:in `run'
/var/lib/postgresql/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/stellar_core_commander-0.0.12/bin/scc:110:in `make_commander': undefined method `mktmpdir' for Dir:Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  mkdir
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a known issue that was solved recently but the updated Gem file was not (yet) published. see: https://github.com/stellar/stellar_core_commander/issues/99

a workaround for this is to provide the --destination flag (see the issue above).

Comment: note: rather than install the gem (as suggested in the readme) its better to build the gem locally with `rake build;rake publish;` that way you're getting the most updated code for the SCC.